# Modifying default KawigiEdit C++ template in Ubuntu 12.10 LTS

Tags: plugins, c++

I am trying to edit default  c++ template of  KawigiEdit plugin, but after I configure and save the modified template as default template, there is no effect.

Has anyone modified KawigiEdit's default C++ template in Ubuntu 12.10 or any other version?

If so what were the steps?
Please help, thanks.

Comment: just to confirm your ubuntu version - Ubuntu 12.10 is not an LTS release.  In-fact it is no longer supported and if you are using this you should already be considering upgrading to 14.04.

Comment: @fossfreedom:I will upgrade,but later on.